# A main menu item is going in drop down menu

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so let me explain the issue to the best of my ability.

I have a JSON (which I covert to array) menu which looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5443672bf5421896488b4567 ) [title] => Home [menutask] => url [task] => home [menulevel] => 0 [order] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 54545bcef542189b4c8b4567 ) [title] => About [menutask] => page [task] => 54545bb8f54218834c8b4567 [menulevel] => 0 [order] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5443670af542187a488b4567 ) [title] => Projects [menutask] => Select [task] => projects [menulevel] => 0 [order] => 3 [submenu] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => iPetFindr [menutask] => page [task] => 544364c0f542186c438b4567 ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 54620183f542187e658b4567 ) [title] => Contact [menutask] => page [task] => 54545bb8f54218834c8b4567 [menulevel] => 0 [order] => 4 ) )
```

I then have my PHP code which should know that unless the submenu is set aka not empty is should list it as a main menu like home and about an projects but if like projects it has a submenu it lists that submenu under projects - which works. but it seems when I try to put Contact or any other menu item after projects it is being added to the bottom of the dropdown for projects.

Now this could be something so simple like I could of forgotten to close something html wise. But I can't see my mistake so I thought I would post my PHP code and see what mistake I have made.

Here is the full navbar - I am using bootstrap as the css framework (sorry for the amount of code)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
           <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="margin:0;">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home"  href="#"><img src="//<?=SITEURL;?>/templates/main/images/small-logo.png" width="40" height="40" alt="RussellHarrower.com"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php
                print_r($menu);
                    foreach($menu as $item){
                      if(empty($item['submenu'])){
                        if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                        {
                          $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $link = array();
                          $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                        }
                      ?>
                        <li <?php if(URI_1 == $link['url']){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>"><?=$item['title'];?></a></li>
                      <?php
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                        {
                          $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $link = array();
                          $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                        }
                      ?>
                            <li class="dropdown
                            <?php if(URI_1 == $link){
                               echo ' active';
                            }?>
                            ">
                              <a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?=$item['title'];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <?php
                                          foreach($item['submenu'] as $submenu)
                                          {
                                            if(MongoId::isValid ($submenu['task']) == 1)
                                            {
                                              $link = self::fetch_link($submenu['task']);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                            $link = array();
                                            $link['url'] = $submenu['task'];
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <li
                                            <?php
                                            if(URI_1 == $link){
                                               echo 'class="active"';
                                            }

                                            echo '><a href="//'; print SITEURL."/".$link['url']; echo'">';
                                            print $submenu['title'];
                                            echo '</a></li>';

                                          }
                                    ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php
                      }
                    }
                    ?>

                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: The closing </ul> for `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` is missing.